# Dojo 1.8 web service call fails with status: 500 error code

Tags: c#, .net, dojo, asmx

```
dojo.xhrPost({
  url: "Default.aspx/TestMethod",
  handleAs: "json",
  contentType: "application/json",
  postData: dojo.toJson({  }),
  load: function (result) {
    debugger;
  },
  error: function (err) {
    debugger;
  }
});
```

That is the script I use to make a request to a `WebMethod` that is exposed in `Default.aspx`. The method is called `TestMethod`.

The error that I get is:

```
Unable to load Default.aspx/TestMethod status: 500
```

If you need any additional information please let me know.

***Note :  I can call the method from the server side and it returns the results as intended.**

Comment: Well it's a 500 error so it's coming from something server side, not from your client side dojo.  Is it possible your web method doesn't handle Json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been there. :(

Usually it is a problem with the format of the data that you are passing in. For instance, if your WebMethod has a parameter that is an int and you are passing a string, you will get a failure like this. 
I would use a tool like Fiddler http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ to see what you are sending to the method.

Also turn on what ever server side logging and tracing that you have and use it. One source that is useful for 500 errors (which tend to happen before "your" server code is reached) is Asp.net health monitoring.
 There is more info about setting that up and using it at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398933(v=vs.100).aspx